# Power BI refresh query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I want to know if there is a way to use the data that is returned from a Power Query I wrote..... For example, my main query would be Query1, which returns a set of data. Now, I'm building another query (Query2), which reference the data from Query1. Is there a way I could duplicated the exact data that is returned from Query1 and use it within Query2 or will Query1 run again when Query2 is ran (since Query2 reference Query1)? I did some research and maybe Table.Buffer would be helpful? Or am I incorrect?

I hope this question is not too confusing.

Please help if possible!

Answer (score 3):

I think I get your question. Once you have a query built, you can either reference it or duplicate it. Referencing the query does not reload it, the data is loaded once.

If you are looking to fetch data for [each](https://www.excelinppc.com/creating-loops-in-power-query/) row in Query 1, you can use `each` to perform loops.

Alternatively you might want to merge Query 2 with Query 1

[image]